NOT NULL column but query with IS NULL on this column continue to make TABLE ACCESS (FULL)
I've a table MyTable with about 400 000 rows. MyColumn is not defined with NOT NULL. But There's a UNIQUE KEY constraint on MyColumn.
When I run this query : SELECT ... FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn IS NULL Oracle does a TABLE ACCESS (FULL). I suppose it's normal because there isn't "NOT NULL" attribute on MyColumn.
So, I've putted "NOT NULL" on MyColumn.
But Oracle continues to make TABLE ACCESS (FULL). If NOT NULL is setted on the column, Oracle should tell itself that there is no query to do since the column cannot, by design, be null. No ?
---EDIT---
SQL Developer explanation show more details on explain than DBeaver. And Oracle seems to know that "NOT NULL" constraint has been setted with or without novalidate.
Without novalidate

With novalidate : the explain is the same as if the "NOT NULL" constraint did not exist.

So, it seems that "NOT NULL" do the job.

Oracle doesn't use an index just because one is available. It's decision as to whether to use an index or a full table scan depends on both whether the index is suitable and whether statistics indicate it would be more performant than a full table scan. There are many situations where it is better to scan the table than use an index.
A predicate of IS NULL will never use a single-column B-tree index because NULLs are not stored in such an index, so the rows you want wouldn't be found. A predicate of IS NOT NULL can use an index but generally will not do so because it will match far too many rows and as such would perform much better with a full table scan.
Lastly, Oracle isn't going to bypass the query just because you shouldn't get any rows (IS NULL on a non-nullable column). A NOT NULL constraint could be non-validated and actually untrue of existing data. Even if it does find situations where it is logically impossible to find rows (e.g. WHERE 1=2) the explain plan will still display a read of the table. If an optimization is added, you may see a special FILTER step with a filter expression that you didn't specify but Oracle added to your query; that indicates that it anticipated a possible optimization. What exactly that optimization is, however, isn't defined in the plan, but known only by experience or by examining wait/trace data to see if it bypasses the table at execution time or not.

Are you sure with this assertion : "A NOT NULL constraint could be non-validated and actually untrue of existing data." ? Because I think Oracle check data content before accepting "NOT NULL" on a column. No ? So I think with NOT NULL attribute on a column, you can be 100% confident that no row contain NULL in this column.

@coutiereric Absolutely: create table t1 (col1 integer null); insert into t1 values (null); alter table t1 modify (col1 not null novalidate); select * from t1;  A NOT NULL attribute is enforced via constraint, and a constraint can be nonvalidated, which enforces the rule for future data but promises nothing about existing data.

thank you for you answer ! It certainly explains why Oracle have to use a TABLE ACCESS (FULL) because it cannot be sure that alls rows contain values for the column.
